# Connecting a button and a text box in Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, dynamic-controls

I'm stuck on this exercise that asks me to create a text box and a button. Each time the button is pressed it is supposed to add 1 to the text box. Anyone know how to approach this?

Comment: What kind of visual basic?  vb6, vb.net, which version of .net (1.0, 2.0, 3.5)?  asp.net/winforms?

Comment: im using vb 2005 express edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i as Integer = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    i += 1
    TextBox1.Text = i.ToString()
End Sub
```

You will also want to protect any attempt to key press in the textbox or set it where Enabled=true.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an event handler to the button
2. When the event is triggered:
3. Read the text value in the text box
4. Convert it to a number
5. Increase the value of the number by one
6. Put that number back to the textbox
7. PROFIT :)

Comment: This doesnt really do much for me, could you explain in terms of code?